# how to read sms from sim dongle using java code and AT commands?

Tags: java, windows-7, sms, command, at-command

I want to read sms from sim which is connected to my laptop by dongle(USB connector) using java code, I know that I have to use AT commands but I don't know which commands and how ???

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows 7 and a reasonably new modem, you don't have to use AT commands.  You can use the Windows Mobile Broadband API (it is available from Win 7 onwards).

It includes interface functions for SMS.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable a serial data connection via the USB connector to your GSM device/phone.

You will also need some type of terminal emulation software to connect and communicate to your phone.

You did not say what Operating system/Hardware you were trying to do this from, or what model of phone, this can affect the AT command set you need to use to access the SMS info, so I can't be more specific.

I have done this a few years ago using a bluetooth connection to a Motorola Razor from a mac Laptop, using a small Realbasic program to send and recieve SMS messages as a proof of concept for sending server monitoring messages to IT staff via sms. You can google the AT for GSM command set.

Comment: thank you... but I still need more help, how can I enable serial data connection via USB?? also how to know which com port is connected. and about the os I use windows 7, and use mobinil dongle to connect the SIM to my laptop.